# How to make out line color different from fill color in turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make my "outline color" different from my "fill color" in turtle but any time I add the second argument to `color()`, which is suppose to be my "fill color", everything just turns black.  If I take out the second color, it uses the first color as both the "outline color" and the "fill color":

```
import turtle

china=turtle.Turtle()

china.color('blue','green')

china.begin_fill()

china.forward(50)
china.left(45)
china.forward(50)
china.left(45)
china.forward(50)
china.left(45)
china.forward(50)
china.left(45)
china.forward(50)
china.left(45)
china.forward(50)
china.left(45)
china.forward(50)
china.left(45)
china.forward(50)
china.end_fill()

turtle.done()
```

The code above gives me a totally black "outline color" and "fill color" why?  Why not a blue "outline color" and green "fill color"?

Comment: And how do we know which Logo interpreter / environment you are using ? :)

Comment: Your code runs fine on my system, generating a green octagon with blue outline.  This may be an issue with your graphics card driver if this is a Windows system.

Comment: If I add 'print(china.color())' before 'turtle.done()' it shows 'blue','green'. And if I use 'print(turtle.color())' it shows 'black,black'. If this is not same for you then you might have some other reference of turtle.Turtle(). Please share your results after this